# Device connection lost after APK install from MacBook

Tags: android, macos, apk, adb

I'm running into a problem on my MacBook Pro.  I type in "adb devices" with my device plugged in and I can see it listed there.  However, when I install the application with "adb install" the connection gets dropped.  This happens both in the Android SDK and in Eclipse.  When I launch it in Eclipse I get this exception:

```
[2012-05-11 08:12:34 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:397)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:102)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I unplug the device and reconnect it and it shows up right until the moment when I try to run the application.

This problem does not seem to happen on my Windows box.

(I do not have tethering on the Macbook and it is disabled on my Android device)

Comment: Does it do that with multiple devices? Or only one?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a driver installed.

Comment: Tim, I only have the one device to test it on.  AlexV, the driver works.  I see the device there.  It goes away AFTER I try to run the application.